# Check for variable declared in child view in parent template

Tags: python, mako

I am migrating several pages over to use our site's new template. These are legacy pages, though, so they need a couple extra global js files.

I was hoping to set a `legacy` flag in the child page views, and then have an `if` check in the master template, but this didn't seem to work.

Is there a better way to do this?

The ideal approach would mean I could simply declare the global legacy scripts in one place. I don't want to have to include them on every legacy child page, which is what we're doing now.

**Parent template:**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5"/>
        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/global.css"/>

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>

        <%block name="page_css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="bc-page-wrapper">
            ${self.body()}
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/globals.js"></script>

        % if legacy == 1:
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/legacy.js"></script>
        % endif
    </body>
</html>
```

**Legacy Page Inheriting Template:**

```
<%
    legacy = true
%>

<%inherit file="/global/ko_admin_template.html" />

<div class="legacy-container">
    content here
</div>
```